# Kubuntu 18.10 blurry screen problem

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, fullscreen

Here what's the thing, when I run any fullscreen app the interface of system becomes incredibly blurry until reboot

Comment: What is "the interface of system"? Have a screenshot before & after?

Comment: Welcome to AU, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1106512/edit) your question including a screenshot of your fullscreen app?

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem.  Text on the screen gets progressively more blurry until the window is redrawn.  Then it becomes sharp again, but immediately gets progressively more blurry.

It seems to be associated with Wesnoth-1.14.  If I reboot it doesn't happen, but starting and then quitting Wesnoth causes it (it doesn't matter whether it is full screen or windowed).  But when Wesnoth is running, there is no problem!  My workaround at the moment is to keep Wesnoth running all the time, and just disable sound when it doesn't have focus ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings > windows management and change the slider from "click to hover" and get your desired outcome.